# php imap foward / redirect account get original address (delivered-to)

Tags: php, imap

I'm trying to do automate stuff with **PHP** and **IMAP**.

I assign a key to every elements I have in my database (e.g. issue tickets) so people can send mails with attachments to `myaccount+key@mycompany.com`. With PHP and IMAP I get the "key" and then assign the body and attachment with the element which has the "key" assigned.

This works wells except when some people wants to redirect automatically a generic e-mail account  to the assigned e-mail address.

So, for instance, I have:

```
Original sender: user1@example.com
Generic e-mail address: issues@alpha.com
Assigned key: 123456
```

They configure to redirect `issues@alpha.com` to `myaccount+123456@mycompany.com`

When I examine `myaccount@mycompany.com` and get the mail, with PHP and IMAP I get the sender, but is `issues@alpha.com` and I want to `get myaccount+123456@mycompany.com` in order to determine where I must put the information.

I try all with PHP IMAP functions but I get nothing although reading the original mail from gmail, I show a `"Delivered-To"` field where is stored the `myaccount+123456@mycompany.com`.

How can I get the delivered-to field?

Thanks a lot.

Regards!

Comment: Fetch the headers, run them through a header/MIME parser, then extract the Delivered-To field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this php function

```
imap_fetchheader ( resource $imap_stream , int $msg_number [, int $options = 0 ] )
```

But this will return whole header of the email.

Here is an example, how I parse Delivered-To:

- $this->connection is connect to imap
- $i is number of message (for test you can use 1)

Example

```
$headers = explode("\n", imap_fetchheader($this->connection, $i));
$head = array();
foreach($headers as $key => $header) {
    $data = explode(":", $header);
    if( count($data) == 2 && !isset($head[$data[0]])) {
        $head[trim($data[0])] = trim($data[1]);
    }
}
```

In $head['Delivered-To'] will be your address.